# How to numerate a Hierachical Table of Contents in PHP out of a parent-child (adjacency) table

Tags: php, mysql, hierarchical

I'm trying to numerate/create or generate a Table of contents in PHP out of a MySQL database in an adjacency tree model (id, parent_id). So far this is what I have achieved when echoing the output.

```
1. Category 1
   1 Subcategory 1
   2 Subcategory 2
   3 Subcategory 3
2.  Category 2
   1. Subcategory 1
      1. Subcategory Subcategory 1
      2. Subcategory Subcategory 2
   2 Subcategory 2
      1 Subcategory 1
      2 Subcategory 2
```

I'm very close, but what the output I want is:

```
1. Category 1
    1.1 Subcategory 1
    1.2 Subcategory 2
    1.3 Subcategory 3
2.  Category 2
   2.1. Subcategory 1
      2.1.1. Subcategory Subcategory 1
      2.1.2. Subcategory Subcategory 2
   2.2 Subcategory 2
      2.2.1 Subcategory 1
      2.2.2 Subcategory 2
```

In other words, I want to use the Table of contents format in a multilevel hierarchical structure as follows: Chapter.Subchapter.Subchapter.Subchapter TITLE.

I have tried by using a recursive array that keeps the current index and concatenates to the previous index but what it ends up adding a weird long number before each item, such,

0.11.**2**..11.2.3.4.5.6.**7**..11..11.2.3.4.5.**6** Computers,

when instead it should be just:

2.7.6 Computers.

(The other numbers are the numbers of the other items)

This is the code I've been working on

```
renumber(0,0,1,0);

function renumber($parent_id,$level=0,$counter=1) {

    // Counter level keeps track of the current index number
    $counterlevel[$level]=$counter;

    $query = "SELECT defaultTitle, id, pid FROM defaultChapters  WHERE  pid=".$parent_id;

    $res = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

    // Exit if there are no tree leafs
    if(mysql_num_rows($res) == 0) {return;}

        while (list ($title, $id) = mysql_fetch_row($res))
    {   

        $leveltext[$level][$counterlevel[$level]] = $section.".".$counterlevel[$level];


        echo str_repeat("......",$level)." ".$counterlevel[$level]." ".$section." ".$title."<BR>";
        // Increase the counter of the current level    
        $counterlevel[$level]++;


        // Initialize the level counter                     
        if(!$counterlevel[$level+1]) {

        $counterlevel[$level+1] = 1;
         }

        // Start the function again to find children
        renumber($id,$level+1,$counterlevel[$level+1]);

    } // End While



}
```

I have browsed all the technical support forums, including this one and it seems nobody has ever published an algorithm for this, simply there is no sample code for this anywhere to be found. There are hundreds of tutorials and codes to get a hierarchical tree in php out of a mysql database without numbering but nothing about numerating a hierarchical Table of Contents in php.

Is it possible to do it with a SQL query too?

Comment: I'd do it in a MySQL user defined function. Alternatively, add a 5th parameter to your function which just hands down the decimal number string which the routine found on the upper level and prepends it to the `echo`.

Answer (score 0):

I would refactor it a little bit and pass along the numbering up to the current invocation:

```
function renumber($parent_id = 0, $level = 0, $prefix = '')
{
    // we don't need pid in the results
    $query = "SELECT defaultTitle, id
        FROM defaultChapters 
        WHERE pid=$parent_id";

    $res = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

    // Exit if there are no tree leafs
    if (mysql_num_rows($res) == 0) {
        return;
    }

    // start numbering at 1
    $nr = 1;
    while (list($title, $id) = mysql_fetch_row($res)) {
        // dropped section, not sure where it was used
        echo str_repeat("......", $level) . " $prefix.$nr $title<BR>";

        // Start the function again to find children
        renumber($id, $level + 1, strlen($prefix) ? "$prefix.$nr." : "$nr.");
        // advance list numbering
        ++$nr;
    }
}

renumber();
```

Comment: Jack, wow, Thanks so much. It worked like  a charm. I was going crazy trying to figure it out. The $section part you were wondering was a the variable you called $prefix and I had a line before to assign some recursive value to it which I deleted unknowingly when I posted my question and when I tried to edit it I realized that I can't edit questions until I have 2000 credit points.